# Is git push --force suitable for forcibly updating a remote file concurrently?

Tags: git, git-push, fast-forward

I am developing an automation script for Jenkins jobs. The script takes a parameter `$1`, makes a small change to a repository file and push the change. It simply does:

```
git clone repo
echo > $1
git commit -a -m 'updated'
git push
```

When those Jenkins jobs execute at once, `git push` fails very often with:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

Which is totally understandable. But I would like to force the push to happen, because it is already guaranteed that each script invocation gets a different `$1`.

From the manual page, I have learned that:

```
--force           
       ... This flag disables these checks,
      and can cause the remote repository to lose commits;
      use it with care.
```

Would the flag be appropriate for my scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not** use `--force`, if you cannot afford losing the other commits and subsequently the other files!

Instead use a pull to pull in the changes of the other processes and push afterwards:

```
git pull origin master && git push origin master
```

In case you want to have your repository clean of merge commits consider using `pull --rebase`:

```
git pull --rebase origin master && git push origin master
```

Note that there is a slight window between the `pull` and the `push` where again commits could slip in, consider repeating the command as necessary if it does not go through. But keep in mind that this could cause a hang.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you. I put the command in a simple loop like this: `for i in {0..4}; do git pull --rebase origin master && git push origin master; done`